# Download a file from FTP where file name contains a certain word c#

Tags: c#, xml, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to download a file from FTP Server where the part of the file name has **"mytestfile"**. The full file name is this **mytestfile123123.xml** 
If I provide the part of the file name, is it possible to amend the code, so it will loop through the files and only pick up the files with the name **mytestfile**

I have written the code below but this is to download the file when I provide the full file name,

```
// Creating a FTP Request
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.KeepAlive = true;

// Enter FTP Server Credentials
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UsePassive = true; // Gets or sets the behaviour of a client application's data transfer process
request.UseBinary = true;
request.EnableSsl = false;

// Fetch the Response and read it into a MemoryStream object
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

// Save the file to the local directory
using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(localDirectory + fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    long length = response.ContentLength;
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int readCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

    readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (readCount > 0)
    {
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
}

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if file exists on FTP - Don't know the name of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607401/check-if-file-exists-on-ftp-dont-know-the-name-of-the-file)

Comment: Use ListDirectoy method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp